# My iPhone settings are not showing Siri

Tags: siri, iphone

I have an iPhone SE with iOS 10.3.1. The Settings app does not show the Siri option. I want to enable *Hey Siri* and I have restrictions disabled.

Here are some screenshots:

**Settings View**

[image]

**Inside General Settings**

[image]

**Inside General Settings Scrolled**

[image]

**Inside General Settings bottom**

[image]

How do I enable *Hey Siri*?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a screenshot of your Settings?

Comment: More specifically, the grouping between **General** and **Privacy**.

Comment: What iPhone version?

Comment: @JashJacob Iphone SE

Comment: What's your iPhone model number?  Go to `Settings -> General -> About` and post your `Model`.  Also, what country are you in?

Comment: @fsb model is MLXP2HN/A, country is India

Comment: It should work with that model in India.  The only other thing I can think of is to do a 1) reset network settings and if that doesn't work, 2) reset all settings.  Something is messed up with Settings and doing a reset might be the only thing that can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue persists after updating to ios 11 also, so I just did a reset all settings and Hey Siri option came back.

PS: the reason I did reset all settings as because springboard kept on crashing almost everyday which became annoying.

Answer (score 3):

This works for iOS 11 and earlier (Restrictions were changed in iOS 12):

The easiest way to get Siri back (without doing a Soft Reset or Reset All Settings), do this:

1. Go to Settings→General→Restrictions
2. **Enable Restrictions**; give it a password.
3. **Disallow** *Siri & Dictation*.
4. Return back to **General** settings.
5. Go back to Restrictions, putting in the password.
6. **Allow** *Siri & Dictation*.  Go back to Settings and *Siri & Search* should now be available.
7. Disable Restrictions.

This worked on an iPhone 6s Plus on iOS 11.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and Reset All Settings fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → General → Restrictions and turn off Siri & Dictation.

Comment: I mentioned in question that restrictions are already disabled

Answer (score -1):

Does Siri turn on when you hold down the Home Button?

The only problem of why you don't see Siri is the restraints,then try to enable them on Siri (looks casually if it appears in the settings) and after remove.

Try to press the Home Button and the Power Button at the same time,for about 10 seconds,until you see the Apple logo.

Comment: Siri does work when home button is pressed for few seconds (2-3 seconds),  also I have already restarted iphone but to no avail.